# Proper way to change calendar date clear icon in DatePicker for AntD

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, antd

I want to change the clear icon of a date picker from the ant design framework.
Is it possible ?

Reason - I want to reset the date to today when it clicks. So close-icon is not appropriate.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since antd uses `rc-picker` to create DatePicker component, you can use `clearIcon` attribute to customize clear icon, but since you need to reset datePicker's value to today with click on clear, you need to do a bit more to handle this requirement, here is an example:

```
function PickerWithCustomClear() {
  const [date, setDate] = React.useState(null);
  const [shoudlReset, setShouldReset] = React.useState(false);

  const onChange = (date) => {
    setDate(date);
    if (!date && shoudlReset) {
      setDate(moment());
      setShouldReset(false);
    }
  };

  return (
      <DatePicker
        onChange={onChange}
        allowClear={true}
        value={date}
        clearIcon={
          // you can use every element here
          <SyncOutlined onMouseDown={(e) => setShouldReset(true)} />
        }
      />
  );
}
```

I've implemented an example you can find it [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jeujuy).

Comment: Great. This works for me.

Comment: Glad I could help.